# Design data structure for Employee-Manager

Tags: java, c#, c++

The question is to design a structure for the employee/manager system.

1) An employee belongs to a manager.

2) A manager has several employees.

3) Manager may also belong to a manager.

4) Employee has only one manager

Design the data structure so that it supports the following operation: delete an employee/manager, promotion(an employee becomes a manager).

Any programming language would suffice.

Note: I do not want code. Just the verbal explanation would be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first idea is to use *employee* as baseclass with a property *manager* as pointer to the manager-object (and other necessary properties like 'id') and a class *manager*, inheriting from *employee* with a list of pointers to employees.

This could be wrapped in a model containing a list of all employees/manager and methods like 'promote (employee)'. Employee could have also a method like 'promote', which returns a manager-object. The manager-class could have a constructor with employee-parameter...

Update (C# code):

```
public class Employee
{

    public string ID;
    public Manager Manager;

    public Manager promote() { return new Manager(this); }

    public Employee() { }

}

public class Manager : Employee
{

    public List<Employee> Employees;

    public Manager() { }
    public Manager(Employee employee) {...}

}

public class EmployeeModel
{

    private List<Employee> employees;
    public List<Employee> Employees { get { return this.employees; } }

    public void addEmployee(...) {...}
    public void removeEmployee(...) {...}
    public void promoteEmployee(...) {...}

}
```

Somehow like this...

Comment: Sorry, could you please draw a UML or give class declarations in pseudo-code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need just one table:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
id integer NOT NULL,
name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
manager_id integer DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This table has a reference to itself (manager_id->id).

If the record has NULL value in "manager_id" field, than it's a top manager. All other records should have some value in "manager_id" field, which is a reference to PrimaryKey field "id"

Comment: +1, that is a good answer but I am looking for something related to data structure. I should have mentioned this clearly. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

from desgin perspective i would use the composite design pattern. [composite digaram]: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Composite_UML_class_diagram_(fixed).svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aComposite_UML_class_diagram_%28fixed%29.svg) . each employee ( which could be a manager ) holds pointer to his manager and each manager holds list of pointers to his employees. but there is only one class ( Employee ).

Comment: Could you explain in bit more detail please? With regards to this example? Thanks

Comment: you should have one class which looks like this: Class Employee { Employee manager; String Name; LevelEnum level; List<Employee> employees; } in case of promotion only change the enum level. in case of simple employee the list of employees would be an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I would say first find out the entities (which you already have, Employee and Manager).
Now find out the relationship based on your constraint :

> Manager to Employee (one to many)
>
> Employee to Manager (one to one)

An employee can be a manager.

Options

1. Have one single `Class` Employee which 'has' (association) `List` of `Employee`
2. Have reference of Employee (as manager, `Employee reportsTo`) in Employee itself.

Area of pain in the above two options :
Option#1 If you delete the manager then List of Employee would go orphan (Employee without manager)
Option#2 if you want to see all employee under a single Manager then you need to iterate through all EMployee for the managers employeeID.

Looking forward for other answers.

Comment: Good approach but has the issues you mentioned. I was asked this in interview and could not answer. I am looking for other answers too.

Comment: you dont have to iterate all the object. you should query the DB only for employees which has a specific manager. SELECT * from EMPLOYEE where manager_id =  "xxxx";